# Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\wamp\www\Drupal\sites\all\modules\entity\entity_token.tokens.inc on line 93

Tags: php, drupal-7, entity, drupal-modules

I keep getting this error when designing a e-commerce website in Drupal using a WAMP server. I am using my localhost to develop at the moment:

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\wamp\www\Drupal\sites\all\modules\entity\entity_token.tokens.inc on line 93"

The module downloaded in Drupal where the error is coming from is 'Entity API'

I look on line 93 but is nothing but commented description therefore don't know where to look. I am new to Drupal and PHP so please can anyone help me? I would upload the code if I knew where to look.

It says in my call stack:

> call_user_func_array ( )  ..\module.inc:895

Thank you in advance really appreciate if someone can help me get to the bottom of this.

```
/**
* Implements hook_token_info_alter().
*/
function entity_token_token_info_alter(&$info) {
$entity_info = entity_get_info();
$token_types = entity_token_types_chained();

// Loop over all chain-able token types, as those may contain further tokens,
// e.g. entity types or 'site'.
foreach ($token_types as $token_type => $type) {
// Just add all properties regardless whether it's in a bundle, but only if
// there is no token of the property yet.
foreach (entity_get_all_property_info($type) as $name => $property) {
  $name = str_replace('_', '-', $name);
  $property += array('type' => 'text', 'description' => $property['label']);
  $property_token_type = _entity_token_map_to_token_type($property);

  if (!isset($info['tokens'][$token_type][$name]) && $property_token_type) {

    $info['tokens'][$token_type][$name] = array(
      'name' => $property['label'],
      'description' => $property['description'],
      'type' => $property_token_type,
      // Mark the token so we know we have to provide the value afterwards.
      'entity-token' => TRUE,
    );
  }
  if ($property_token_type == 'struct' && !empty($property['property info'])) {
    $info['tokens'][$token_type][$name]['dynamic'] = TRUE;
    $help = array();
    foreach ($property['property info'] as $key => $property_info) {
      $help[] = $key . ' (' . $property_info['label'] . ')';
    }
    $info['tokens'][$token_type][$name]['description'] .= ' ' . t('The following properties may be appended to the token: @keys',
      array('@keys' => implode(', ', $help))
    );
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: I mean the drupal forums literally have patches available for your deployment to resolve this issue...

Comment: Drupal patches do not show the solution, just has a browse and the patches are in relation to different functions

Comment: It isn't possible that commented-out code triggers fatal errors. Did you review the correct file? Did you count lines manually?

Comment: I counted the lines manually. I have edited my post with the lines 85-130 included. I also reviewed the correct file. I will try checking if commented-out code does trigger fatal errors by deleting them from the file.